# How can I configure VSCode to automatically change .contains() to .includes() for Arrays in JavaScript files in real time while typing?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Despite having used JS for 5+ years now, I cannot seem to remember that the Array method .contains() is not valid JS and you instead have to use .includes()

Is there a way I can configure VSCode to automatically fix this mistake for me in real time as I am programming? I have used Atom most of my life so I am not very familiar with what is possible and not, but I assume this should be possible?

I though about using the User snippets to suggest includes if I type contains however, I am only seeing the snippet if I type contains without anything in front of it with is never the case so I this solution is not working for me

**EDIT:** I just realized that there is a contains() method for DOM elements. I was originally just talking about the Array method includes() where contains() would not work. This means I can't just change all instances of x.contains() to x.includes(), but instead I would need to make VSCode suggest the correct method based off if I am typing it after an Array or a DOM element. Though I feel doubtful this is possible, I'll remain optimistic and leave the question up.

Comment: You'd do this via ESLint, but it wouldn't change your code for you, it would just give you a warning + squigglylines: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Comment: FWIW, I expect `.contains()` to be fully supported in JS for decades to come (after-all, `substr()` is still with us), even if it is non-standard - so I wouldn't sweat it too much unless you're targeting some _uber-strict_ JS engine.

Comment: you can try if the extension I wrote [Replace On](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.replace-on) would make the typing/correcting easier

Comment: @Dai I just realized that there is a contains() method for DOM elements in JS. I was originally just talking about the Array method includes() where contains() would not work. This makes me doubt I will be able to make VSCode suggest the correct method based off if I am typing it after an Array or a DOM element, but I'll remain optimistic and leave the question up